# Euler #1 in Python, wrote program but got wrong answer

Tags: python, math

I've decided I want to work on the Euler problems in order to improve my Python skills, but I ran into a problem with the first one. You see, I wrote the program I thought would work trying to get an answer, and compared it to the one found on the solutions page located [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/Project%20Euler%20Solutions). Here is the code that I wrote:

```
total = 0

for x in range(1000):
    if x % 5 != 0 and x % 3 != 0:
        total += x
print(total)
```

This gives me the answer 266,332, when the correct answer is 233,168 according to the solution linked before. I don't know why I got the wrong answer, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your total+= line needs intended. Not sure if that's a copy paste problem, though

Comment: If it wasn't indented, it would produce an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Ah, yes. You are summing all numbers that *aren't* multiples and 3 or 5

Comment: Please reformat your code snippet - as it is currently formatted it produces this: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `not` in your application of De Morgan's Law:

```
total = 0

for x in range(1000):
    if not (x % 5 != 0 and x % 3 != 0):
        total += x
print(total)
```

`not (x % 5 != 0 and x % 3 != 0)` is equivalent to `x % 5 == 0 or x % 3 == 0`, the latter of which is stated in the page you link as the equivalent `not x%5 or not x%3`.

Comment: don't forget the indentation.

Comment: @silentphoenix - What's wrong with the indentation?

Comment: My apologies. Nothing is wrong with yours, but the OP had a problem with the indentation. That would probably be a good thing to point out along with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @silentphoenix - If the OP's indentation was wrong in his actual code, it would produce `IndentationError` instead of a wrong number. It's a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong condition. You have to test, when the rest is 0? With 3 and with 5. Additionally you have to use OR instead AND because you want both group of numbers.

If you use AND you are going to get only the numbers that are multiple of both, multiple of 3 and multiple of 5.

Try:

```
total = 0

for x in range(1000):
    if x % 5 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        total += x
print(total)
```

Comment: You should explain why @Patrick's answer doesn't work and this one does, instead of just dumping code

Comment: I think he explained it fairly well, and I see now that I just made a careless mistake in the if.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong with the program. For starters, your `if` statement checks the wrong condition--it checks to see whether or not it is NOT divisible by 3 or 5. It should be `if x%3==0 or x%5==0:`

Second, you have an indentation error, so nothing is being executed by the `if` statement. Indent the `total+=x` statement.

Your final code will look like this:

```
total = 0
for x in range(1000):
    if x % 5 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        total += x
print(total)
```

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

1. try this:

   ```
   def sumOfMultiples(number):
       sum = 0
       for i in range(1,number):
           if i % 2 == 0 or i % 3 == 0:
               sum += i
       return sum

   print (sumOfMultiples(15))
   ```